# How to determine dimensions/area of hexagons in geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've currently plotted x and y coordinates to ggplot using geom_hex.

**I'm wondering if it's possible to determine size of the hexagons plotted? 
(or at least the width of each?)**

I recognize they will be in arbitrary units but that is OK. If A) my plot is approximately 50 by 40 (see below) and B)geom_hex(bins = 60) is it accurate to infer that there are 60 hexagons across each x and y dimension;

Therefore, my approximate hexagon width would be 40(x-units)/60(hexagons) = 0.66667?

**Thanks for the help!**

[image: My Plot so far]

Comment: I found a solution: you can pre-specify the width of each bin within geom_hex with binwidth =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: you can pre-specify the width of each bin within geom_hex with binwidth = –